# Why do we use nested message send for alloc in object-c?

Tags: objective-c

For allocation and initialization to a class, we do

```
Party *partyInstance = [Party alloc];
[partyInstance init];
```

or

```
Party *partyInstance = [[Party alloc] init];
```

Is there any special reason to use nested message? Or is it just for convenience?

Comment: just convenience.  It is used so often that there is no "understanding" benefit to splitting it into two lines

Comment: @Ben: No. The first version is *wrong* because `init` might return a object which is different to the one being passed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is. You need to assign to your object the return value of `init`, not that of `alloc` (because of [class clusters](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/ClassCluster.html)). And writing

```
Party *partyInstance = [Party alloc];
partyInstance = [partyInstance init];
```

would be quite awkward.